# Simple assembly code conversion to Java

Tags: java

I want to convert the following code into Java code. I think it is assembly code, but not sure. The part that I really do not get is `y -= m < 3;`.

```
int dow(int y, int m, int d)
{
    static int t[] = {0, 3, 2, 5, 0, 3, 5, 1, 4, 6, 2, 4};
    y -= m < 3;
    return (y + y/4 - y/100 + y/400 + t[m-1] + d) % 7;
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

That's C code, and I believe this

```
static final int t[] = { 0, 3, 2, 5, 0, 3, 5, 1, 4,
  6, 2, 4 };

static int dow(int y, int m, int d) {
  if (m < 3) {
    y--;
  }
  return (y + y / 4 - y / 100 + y / 400 + t[m - 1] + d) % 7;
}
```

is equivalent. Because `y -= m < 3;` will evaluate to `y-=1;` if `m<3` otherwise `y-=0;`. Instead you can use a simple `if`. Finally the `t[]` can't be static in a method in Java.

Answer (score 3):

The boolean `m < 3` will evaluate to `0` or `1`. Then the operation `y -=` makes more sense.

In java, it would look more like:

`y -= (m<3 ? 1 : 0)`

Answer (score 0):

You code in Java would be

```
public static void main(String[] args){
    int calculated_value = dow(2014, 7, 31);
}   

public static int dow(int y, int m, int d){
    int t[] = {0, 3, 2, 5, 0, 3, 5, 1, 4, 6, 2, 4};
    y -= (m < 3 ? 1 : 0);
    return (y + y/4 - y/100 + y/400 + t[m-1] + d) % 7;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I see that you already have a few good literal translations of the code in other answers, but what you really want to write is the following, which is clear, readable, and relies on a trusted library:

```
public static int dow(int y, int m, int d)
{
    Calendar c = Calendar.getInstance();
    c.set(Calendar.YEAR, y);
    c.set(Calendar.MONTH, m - 1);
    c.set(Calendar.DAY_OF_MONTH, d);

    return (c.get(Calendar.DAY_OF_WEEK) - 1);
}
```

The `- 1` at the end is only to map the numeric day-of-week representation that Java uses (where Sunday=1 and Saturday=7) to the same mappings as in the original code. Similar with the `m - 1` too.

Answer (score 0):

### Here is my conversion to Java:

```
package datecalculator;

import javax.swing.*;

public class DateCalculator {

    public static int calculateDay(int y, int m, int d){

        //Tomohiko Sakamoto's method
        int t[] = {0, 3, 2, 5, 0, 3, 5, 1, 4, 6, 2, 4};
        y -= (m < 3 ? 1 : 0);
        return (y + y/4 - y/100 + y/400 + t[m-1] + d) % 7;
    }

    public static void main(String[] args){

        //Receiving input
        int y = Integer.parseInt(JOptionPane.showInputDialog("Enter the year"));
        int m = Integer.parseInt(JOptionPane.showInputDialog("Enter the month"));
        int d = Integer.parseInt(JOptionPane.showInputDialog("Enter the day"));

        //Calling Tomohiko Sakamoto's method
        int answer = calculateDay(y, m, d);

        //Output
        if (answer == 0){JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, "Sunday");}
        if (answer == 1){JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, "Monday");}
        if (answer == 2){JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, "Tuesday");}
        if (answer == 3){JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, "Wednesday");}
        if (answer == 4){JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, "Thursday");}
        if (answer == 5){JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, "Friday");}
        if (answer == 6){JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, "Saturday");}
    }   

}
```